# setString vs. setStringValue in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa

I tried to use the method setString to change the text in a textfield and it didn't work. Then I changed it to setStringValue and it worked. So what is setString used for?

Comment: Please don't tag a question as “xcode” (or “xcode3.2”, or “xcode3.2.3”, or anything like that) unless it actually has to do with the Xcode IDE. This question is about Cocoa.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NSTextField` does not have a `setString:` method. `NSTextField` is a type of `NSControl`, and `NSControl` has a `setStringValue:` method.

`NSText` and its more famous subclass `NSTextView` have a `setString:` method. @John Boker is correct that the field editor is an `NSText`, but you still can't send `setString:` to an `NSTextField`, even in edit mode. You'd need to get the field editor from the window and then call `setString:` on that (not that you really should do that).

While it is confusing to newcomers, there is a good rationale behind the different methods. `NSControl` has a "value", and that value can take different types (`setDoubleValue:`, `setObjectValue:`, etc.) This allows me to set the value as a double, but then retrieve in as a string. For the broad range of possible controls, this makes good sense and is very flexible. `NSText` is not a control; note how it doesn't have `setAction:` or `setTarget:` either. Its purpose is to display and edit (attributed) strings. When you call `string`, you are actually getting the real backing text storage, not just the value of the object in string form (as `stringValue` does for `NSControl`).

That said, when you say "it didn't work," I hope you mean that you got a compiler warning about this that told you that `NSTextField` may not respond to `setString:`. If you're ignoring compiler warnings, then you're going to have a lot of problems in ObjC.

Comment: Going further into the “value” notion: Many NSControls (such as sliders) have a numeric value, and `stringValue` is no less valid for them. You can ask for the control's value as a `double` (`doubleValue`), a `float` (`floatValue`), an `int` (`intValue`), an `NSInteger` (`integerValue`), or a decimal text representation in an NSString object (`stringValue`), and set the value as any of those types using their matching setter methods. One value, many types. Unlike a control, a text view doesn't have this; it just has its string.

Answer (score 2):

from: http://macosx.com/forums/software-programming-web-scripting/43905-_outlet-setstring-testing-selector-not-recognized.html#5

> setString: is for NSText, which is the
>   class used for an NSTextField's field
>   editor while it is being edited, and
>   for the NSText subclass NSTextView
>   which can display and edit styled text
>   as in TextEdit.

So the way i take it is you can only use setString: when the field is in an edit mode, i think.

Answer (score 1):

Going a bit more generically (in contrast to my comment on Rob's answer):

Objects respond to messages. You can send a message to any object that responds to that message; you can't send a message to any object that doesn't respond to it.

Instances of NSText and its subclass NSTextView respond to `setString:`, so you can send NSText objects and NSTextView objects `setString:` messages.

Instances of NSControl and its subclasses, including NSTextField, respond to `setStringValue:`, so you can send NSControl objects, NSTextField objects, and other control objects `setStringValue:` messages.

See Rob's answer and my comment on it for *why* these two specific branches of the class hierarchy have these seemingly-similar-but-differently-named methods.